# Rails 4 + ActiveRecord: How to exclude some records from the search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

I have these tables:

1. `users` - a classic Devise table
2. `listings` - users create listings
3. `listings_exclude_users` - 2 columns: `user_id` and `listing_id`

user.rb

```
class User 
  has_many :listings
end
```

listing.rb

```
class Listing
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :listing_excluded_users
end
```

listing_excluded_user.rb

```
class ListingExcludedUser
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :listing
end
```

I label some users for which shouldn't be the respective listing visible and this information is saved in `listings_exclude_users`.

Now I'd like to run a query that would fetch all the listings, but if is signed in the user who is in the table `listings_exclude_users` for the specific listing, then don't fetch this listing.

I can do it in the view, but I'd prefer the ActiveRecord way.
I tried

```
@listings = Listing.joins(:listing_excluded_users).where("listings.status='0' AND (listing_excluded_users.user_id != '#{current_user.id}')")
```

But this query doesn't return anything (empty `@listings`).

Thank you in advance for advice.

Comment: what database are you using? mysql? postgres?

Comment: Never, ever do something like "...#{varname}" in a SQL fragment. Maybe you are safe this time, but some day you get a SQL injection. You should learn how to use parameters in the SQL statement.

Comment: In this case, #{current_user.id} is safe as its probably not user input, however, yes, good practice to use parameters as I've rewritten the queries below.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done in two queries. If you need one query, you may need a subquery.

2 queries:

```
user_ids_to_exclude = ListingExcludedUser.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:user_id)
@listings = Listing.where.not(user_id: user_ids_to_exclude)
```

Subquery

```
@listings = Listing.where.not(user_id: ListingExcludedUser.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).select(:user_id))
```

NOTE: where.not is a Rails 4 idiom.

Comment: Thank you, `Peter`, for your answer. However, how is this query different from the one in the OP? Anyway, the issue is that the output is an empty array. If I have 10 listings in the DB table and I decide that I don't want to make the first one visible for a user, the rest 9 should be displayed there.

Comment: The key is '<>' and not '!='. This is how you do NOT in sql.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is the type of join you are doing. By doing an inner join you will exclude rows that are not in the exclusion table which is the opposite of what you want! See my edit above to use OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Yes, the inner join is wrong. Outer join is not enough, as a Listing may have been excluded by two users, one of it is the current user. the outer join then still returns it, because there is another user that is not the current user. Not conditions are not so easy in the SQL logic.

Comment: the OP did not mention needing to check multiple users, @user984621 - can you clarify if your question requires multiple users to be included in the exclusion query? If so, please update the question above.